# AssertTrue missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, typeerror, assert

I am trying to assert the presence of an element and I can make it work but now in the way that I would like.

I have a common functions file: -

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def is_element_present_common(self, how, what):
    try:
        self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        return False
    return True
```

...and my main file: -

```
import unittest
from Common import common_functions, initialisation, login
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class QuickTestPlanLogin(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = initialisation.start_webdriver()
        self.driver = initialisation.start_sap(self.driver)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try:
            self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e:
            return False
        return True

    def test_login(self):
        wait = initialisation.wait_for(self.driver)
        self.driver = login.default_login(self.driver, "username", "password")

        # self.assertTrue(self.is_element_present(By.ID, "my-projects-table_info"))
        # self.assertTrue(common_functions.is_element_present_common(By.ID, "my-projects-table_info"))
```

There are two assert statements. If I run the first one it works fine, but it is calling the is_element_present function which I do not want. I would like to call the is_element_present_common function from the common_functions file. Every time I run the second assert statement I get the following error: -

```
TypeError: is_element_present() missing 1 required positional argument: 'what'
```

I know I am missing something very simple....

Comment: Any function that takes `self` as an argument is intended to be a method. So it should be inside a class, and should be called via `instance.method_name()`. If it is _not_ supposed to be in a class, it should not have a `self` parameter.

Comment: Just tried placing `is_element_present_common` inside a class and I'm getting the same error. I've already tried removing the `self` parameters, but can't get the syntax right as it keeps giving me another error: -   `NameError: name 'driver' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, put the wrong error in, this is what I'm getting after placing inside a class: - `TypeError: is_element_present_common() missing 1 required positional argument: 'what'` which is the same as the original error message...?!?

Comment: don't use `self` in your function declaration... it's only for methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the function definition to :

```
def is_element_present_common(how, what):
```

And

Change the call to `is_element_present_common` function as :

```
self.assertTrue(common_functions.is_element_present_common(By.ID, "my-projects-table_info"))
```

Comment: I tried this and get a different error: - `TypeError: is_element_present_common() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'how' and 'what'`

Comment: @Northers Check my updated Answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Okay, I tried removing self from the function declaration and it then complained about `self` not being defined so then I removed self from before driver and it then complained about `driver` not being defined so i then added `driver` to the function declaration and it has gone back to telling me about the missing positional argument 'what'. I have noticed that when writing the assert statement it is seeing the "my-projects-table_info" as the `how` part of the method so it sees that the `what` part is missing....

Comment: Not sure whether the syntax is nice, but this seems to work now - `self.assertTrue(common_functions.is_element_present_common(self.driver, By.ID, "my-projects-table_info"))`

Comment: @Northers Well, there's nothing wrong to be innovative & design new protocols & solution. If it have worked, that's great !!!